# Can superscripts only be used in $-delimited mathematical formulas?

Tags: superscripts

`A^{\dag}` got error "Missing $ inserted"

Is there a way to use superscripts not in mathematical formulas?

Comment: Welcome to TeX,SE. If `A` is (math) variable, than had to be in math environment. In your case in text as `$A^{\dag}$` in display math for example as `\begin{equation} A^{\dag} ...\end{equation}`. Strictly use LaTeX syntax for in-line math expression you should write `\(A^{\dag}\)`

Comment: If my A is not a mathematical variable, I don't want to put it in $$. For example, I want apple^{\dag}. @Zarko

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `\textsuperscript`, e.g. `A\textsuperscript{\dag}`, in either math or text mode.